# Что такое #doctest: +ELLIPSIS ... и как заставить его работать?

Tags: python

Часто при чтении книги "Fluent Python"  в русском переводе "Python. К вершинам мастерства" в тексте примеров кода встречается странный комментарий типа:

```
gen123 #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
```

у меня при этом выдается следующее:

```
>>><function gen123 at 0x00000235F7152598>
```

а в учебнике так:

```
>>><function gen123 at 0x...>
```

Вопрос - что Это за #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
и почему у меня он не до конца срабатывает?
ПыСы: По просьбам трудящихся привожу код функции полностью как есть, хотя не думаю, что это имеет какое-то значение:

```
def gen123():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
```

[image: страницы книги]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaxU   -  если вы имеете ввиду литерал """ .....""" после def gen123():   то его нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) позволяет создавать тесты из примеров, скопированных из Питон консоли (REPL):

```
>>> list(range(20)) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
[0, 1, ..., 18, 19]
```

`doctest` модуль проверяет, что код возвращает именно тот результат, который показан. Таким образом вы можете быть уверены, что docstring в Питон-коде, другая документация являются актуальными и примеры работают как задокументировано.

[`+ELLIPSIS`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS) позволяет заменить произвольный вывод на `...` (многоточие).

К примеру, если ввести:

```
>>> list(range(20))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

то видно что действительный вывод другой. `+ELLIPSIS` позволяет не приводить лишние подробности или игнорировать зависящие от окружения результаты (чтобы тесты более читаемыми и переносимыми были).

Comment: спасибо - и что в моем случае сделано не так?
почему +ELLIPSIS не срабатывает? Вопрос наполовину в этом.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets вы не запускаете doctest. С точки зрения Питон интерпретатора `#..` — это обычный комментарий.

Comment: я делаю все так же как в учебнике. см. приведенную страницу. модуль я подключил... у него из интерпретатора - работает, а у меня - нет :-(
или я совсем что то не понимаю?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: нажмите на ссылку в вопросе, там показаны несколько способов как doctest запускается. Вывод с многоточием это просто статический текст в docstring или *.rst файле. Это представление **ожидаемого** вывода (сравните ожидаемый вывод в первом примере в ответе и действительный вывод во втором примере). В вопросе у вас показан живой сеанс, активная Python REPL — никакого отношения к doctest. Просто команда `python` сама по себе не запускает `doctest` функции. `import doctest` также не запускает. Если у вас `pythom -mdoctest` или `doctest.testmod()` не работают, то обновите вопрос.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что запустить интерпретатор "в режиме" "doctest"  невозможно?
ведь приведенный код из учебника не выведет из файла ничего кроме 1 2 3

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: 1- doctest работает со **статическим** текстом (в исходном коде внутри [`*.py` файла](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/test/test_unpack_ex.py), в документации в [`*.rst` файле](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/library/doctest.rst). Python REPL -- это **интерактивное** окружение (код с клавиатуры вводится динамически). Вы можете `python -mdoctest ваш_модуль.py` или `python -m doctest руководство.rst` запустить. 2- Нет, не выведет: разницу между `gen`, `gen()`, `list(gen())` в отдельном вопросе можно обсудить.